# Apply QML DropShadow invalid, error hint and hint for "QML DropShadow: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling."

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Codes show as below:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        contentHeight: 38

        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#477aa0"
        }

        TabButton {
            id: tabBtn1
            width: 129
            height: 36
            text: qsTr("Plate Layout")
            anchors.top: parent.top
            background: Rectangle {
                color: "#ffffff"
            }
        }

        //is tabBtn1's sibling!
        DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: tabBtn1
            horizontalOffset: 3
            verticalOffset: 4
            radius: 5
            samples: 11
            color: "#000"
            opacity: 0.75
            source: tabBtn1
        }
    }
}
```

If **TabBar** change to **Rectangle** and **TabButton** change to **Button**, it works.As far as I know，qml included in brackets by **Menu**. I guess it is bug of Qt lib, maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is because a `DropShadow` is not a `TabButton`, which causes [this function](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquicktabbar.cpp?id=28454b503c7e77a85855e1cc5911908d46d29366#n343) to return false and it is not [parented](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquickcontainer.cpp?id=28454b503c7e77a85855e1cc5911908d46d29366#n244) to the effective `contentItem` like the `TabButton` is. Note that the [`contentItem`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/TabBar.qml?id=28454b503c7e77a85855e1cc5911908d46d29366#n50) is a `ListView`, so making the `DropShadow` a child of it and trying to make it then fill the `TabButton` probably wouldn't work anyway.

An easier solution is to use [layers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers):

```
    TabButton {
        id: tabBtn1
        width: 129
        height: 36
        text: qsTr("Plate Layout")
        anchors.top: parent.top
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#ffffff"
        }

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.effect: DropShadow {
            anchors.fill: tabBtn1
            horizontalOffset: 3
            verticalOffset: 4
            radius: 5
            samples: 11
            color: "#000"
            opacity: 0.75
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx first. I know the method you provide. But I still think there might be a bug of qt lib. If we can use some feature in two method, I think either of the two should be valid in any time, anywhere.Even now, **DropShadow**  should probably have a NOTE.

Comment: " If we can use some feature in two method, I think either of the two should be valid in any time, anywhere." I'm not sure I understand what you're saying here, but I'll take a stab: no, putting a DropShadow in a ListView and making it fill a sibling is not expected to work. Try doing it outside of TabBar and let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Sorry,I may not be clear about what I expressed.I mean one good lib should work in the same invocation. The second best for having a correct complaint or a doc notation.Sorry for my poor English again.